# Using tidyquant data with quantstrat

Tags: r, quantstrat, tidyquant

I have some futures data retrieved from Quandl via the `tq_get` function from `tidyquant`

```
## list of agricultural commodities
agriculturals <- c("CHRIS/ICE_CC2", "CHRIS/ICE_KC2", "CHRIS/ICE_ICN2", "CHRIS/ICE_CT2", "CHRIS/CME_LB2", "CHRIS/CME_O2", "CHRIS/CME_S2", "CHRIS/ICE_SB2", "CHRIS/CME_LC2", "CHRIS/CME_W2", "CHRIS/CME_RR2", "CHRIS/ICE_OJ2", "CHRIS/ICE_IS2", "CHRIS/ICE_ISM2", "CHRIS/ICE_IBO2")

# build dataframe
ag <- 
    agriculturals %>%
      tq_get(get          = "quandl",
             from         = "2000-01-01",
             collapse     = "daily") %>% 
    select(date, symbol, everything())
```

I would like to use this data for strategy backtesting in the `quantstrat` package. From what I can tell I need to somehow load this data to the environment using the `getSymbols` function in order to use the data with the `quantstrat` functions. Does anyone know if this is possible and if so how to achieve it?

Comment: But why do you think you need `tidyquant` when your goal is `quantstrat`? You could just use the `Quandl` package.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. Would you mind sharing an example of how I could use the Quandl package to bring up these data in a format that can be used with quantstrat?

Comment: From what I can tell I can't use the "getSymbols" function to access these data from "Quandl" where as I was able to use the "tq_get" function from "tidyquant".

Comment: You should ask the package authors or community for help. But I can assurre that as `quanstrat` predates `tidyquant` by several years that there is no requirement for the latter by the former.  Good luck -- I don't use either much but occassionally download from Quandl the namesake package.

Comment: I was able to figure this out with help from Ilya Kipnis's packages "IKTrading". The quandClean function can be used to bring in futures data from Quandl and stitch together a continuous series. CME_GC <- quandClean("CHRIS/CME_GC", start_date=from, end_date=to, verbose=verbose) #Gold. This can then be made available to quantstrat  via stock("CME_GC", currency="USD", multiplier=1).